# Right preposition for: Evaluation of a function at 0 "in/at" its first argument

Tags: mathematics

Consider a function *f(x,y)* defined on *X* x *Y*.

One says that *f(0,y)* is the evaluation of *f* at 0 ...

1. ... **in** its first argument
2. ...**at** its first argument
3. (none of these)

My problem using searching engines is that  usual occurrence of evaluation is *evaluation at certain point*, but if the function in question has multiple arguments, then which preposition helps to specify the argument it is evaluated in/at?

Comment: A homework question?

Comment: @BillJ  sounds more like c.p. is the teacher trying to write the question.

Comment: It's not clear how you can "evaluate" a function that has two arguments when you only provide the one argument -- or rather the result will be some *range* of values.  So I'm not sure that "evaluate" is even the right term for this.  It's been a long time since I took any serious math classes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about specialized terminology that most native speakers would need to look up.

Comment: You probably want the value of *f* **with** zero **as** its first argument.  The preposition "at" leads us to believe that there's a single argument -- even if that one argument is a set of values (e.g. coordinates).  That's why you're getting so many search engine results for "evaluation at a certain point".

Comment: It's a matter of opinion what the full "right" answer might be, but ***none of these*** is certainly part of it. Even specialised math terminology wouldn't admit of ***f(0,y) is the evaluation of f AT 0...,*** regardless of whatever string of words follows. As a syntactically credible rephrasing though, you might start with ***f(0,y) is the evaluation of f WITH 0** [as [the value of] the first argument].*

Comment: Well, "evaluation at [certain point]" is *the* terminology in specialised math. So I thought it was natural to extend this terminology to multi-varialbe functions (functionals, and other objects). I don't see why it should change, but you probably know the reason.

Comment: The word "certain" is meaningful.  A coordination like ***( 0, y )*** or ***( x, 0 )***, where at least one component of the coordination is not specifically established, is *not* a *certain* point.  It's a potentially infinite range of points, or a decidedly **un**certain point, or perhaps something else.  It doesn't agree with the specificity of the preposition "at" in this context.  **At** a point, but **in** a range or **through** a continuum or **with** a constraint.  In the context that you've established, you've provided one constraint but left at least one other constraint uncertain.

Answer (score 2):

Math has its own unique way of saying things, so this isn't really a general-purpose English question.  I'm not sure if "evaluate" is the right verb to use when talking about defining a function of two variables when only one variable *is known*, as the result is another function, not a specific value.

Which is why I have some trouble figuring out what to say, since it's not clear what you're trying to do.  For example if I were to try to explain the problem I might say something like:

> Given a function *f(x,y)*, then *f(0,y)* **is a reduction of** the function when x=0.  Similarly we can say *f(n,y)* reduces/simplifies the function when the first argument **is known** to be *n*.

My verbiage is probably a little strange, as it's been a long time since I've taken any serious math courses.  Someone who does this on a regular basis could better tell you what terms would be common.

Comment: Ok thanks. The origin is something like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879514/pure-states-of-ck-are-evaluation-functions, and the  but I tried to avoid technicalities, which perhaps are necessary.

Comment: @c.p.  Well, all that goes right over my head.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that there is a unique way to translate f(0, y) into English. The whole point of mathematical notation is to provide a succinct and less ambiguous form of communication than any natural language. Moreover, there are usually many ways to convey the same thought in a natural language.

In most cases, I would avoid the word "evaluation" because it implies a numeric answer. If there is no numeric answer, "evaluation" creates a misleading expectation. "f(0, y) is the simplification of f(x, y) in the special case that x equals zero" seems to me to work, but there are probably hundreds of ways to express the same thought in English.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the context that this question concerns a function from two-dimensional real space (RxR) into the real line R. That assumption helps me explain my answer but does not change it.

According to Burkill and Burkill *A Second Course in Mathematical Analysis*, the word that describes a function, such as f(0, y), which takes values that are identical to another function (in this case f(x, y)) but on a subset of the latter's domain (in this case the line x=0 is a proper subset of RxR) is the **restriction** of f to the the subset.

I daresay there are other terms used by other authors. In quite a few years of studying mathematics I myself have not encountered in this context either 'simplification' (*pace* @JeffMorrow) or 'reduction' (*pace* @Andrew) but it is quite possible that they are used also.

If you want to refer specifically to the values taken by f(0, y), they are its range.

Comment: That's right. However, if you are interested in the algebra A of all real valued functions defined on X x Y (yes,suppose X, and Y are subsets of the real line R), instead of a fixed function, and you consider the map Ev_{p,q}: A----> R, given by Ev_{p,q}(f) = f(p,q), for fixed points p,q of X and Y respectively, traditionally in functional analysis this is called *evaluation*.  My doubt is not about this terminology (I am 100% sure of) but about the preposition.

Comment: "for fixed points p,q of X and Y". You did not say in your question that y was a fixed point. If it is, then I am in no doubt that the preposition is "at". And even if y is not a fixed point in R, (0, y) is a point in the set of lines in the space XxY, so you could still use "at (0,y)". I do have doubts about using the words "...first argument". I do not recall ever seeing that usage.